# Как организовать Long Polling на сервере.

Tags: php

Я не до конца понимаю как будет работать этот метод. Допусти я отправил запрос на сервер и зациклил его, до получения новых данных. Как мне получить новые данные, если запрос завис и он не может отправить на сервер новые данные?

Comment: Это не в ту степь, это про передачу от сервера к клиенту... т.е. клиент отправляет серверу запрос, и сервер молчит пока у него не появятся "новые" данные

Comment: а как же тогда организовать реал тайм на странице? Допустим у меня запускается крон каждую минуту и нужно чтобы сервер отслеживал только что поступившие данные и выводил на страницу

Comment: Так об этом и идет речь, сервер висит в цикле и проверяет наличие новых данных(как - это уже от вашей реализации зависит), как только данные появились - отправляет их клиенту, при этом соединение с клиентом закрывается а клиент устанавливает новое соединение, сервер соединение новое принимает, и опять ждет пока у него появятся новые данные, и так по кругу =) LongPooling - это способ в нужное время отправить от сервера к клиенту, клиент и так может отправлять запросы на сервер в любое время....

Comment: я не особо шарю. А как мне запустить цикл на сервере? Через ajax?. Клиент заходит на страницу и как сервер будет зациклен?

Comment: Спасибо, всё понял. Я записываю данные в файл. Просто перезаписал значения файла и цикл прервался.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложил использование веб-сокета https://socket.io/
Long polling будет дергать постоянно базу (или что то другое в зависимости от вашей реализации) на предмет того пришли ли сообщения или нет. Куда более эффективнее использовать веб сокеты.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: а что тут можно добавить, ссылку на пример я скинул, long polling не знаю когда слышал в последний раз это слово, прошлый век, у вас бесконечный цикл в котором периодически дергаете базу/ файлы на предмет получения новых сообщений, веб сокет держит постоянное соединение и слушает определенный канал, как только в канал что то прилетает у вас срабатывает event на получение и в нем что хотите уже делайте

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)